# How to detect in TypeScript code if it's run in Deno or in Browser compiled by Deno?

Tags: typescript, deno

How to detect in TypeScript code if it's run in Deno or in Browser compiled by Deno?

Run in Browser I mean - TS compiled by Deno to JS and executed by Browser.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ("Deno" in window) {
  console.log("window.Deno=", window.Deno);
} else {
  console.log("no Deno here");
}
```

And you might also need this in ***tsconfig.json***:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "lib": ["dom", "deno.ns", "esnext"],
    // ...
  }
}
```